# Show custom taxonomies in admin panel under custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, admin-menu

I have added a custom post type called "product" to my theme.
I have also created a custom taxonomy for this post type called "product_category".

In the admin panel, the custom taxonomy shows up under the custom post type (product) like so:

[image: Screenshot of current custom post type]

If the user adds terms to my custom taxonomy (eg: 'kitchenware' & 'Painting'), I would like the terms to show up in the admin where 'Product Categories' currently shows. I have photoshopped an example to show what I need to achieve.

[image: What I need to Achieve]

When the users clicks on these terms, they are brought to edit.php where they are shown only products with the term they clicked.

Is this possible with Wordpress? It seems like something that should be part of wordpress functionality.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean »kitchenware« and »painting« are terms in the »product_category« taxonomy. It'd be possible to do this, but you have to consider that there could be hundreds of terms. Do you really want them all listed like you described? In my mind this would be a user interface (experience) disaster. I'd advice you to look around for a option to sort/filter on the edit screen. There are some solutions for this on here.

Comment: do you mean taxonomies (multiple), or taxonomy *terms* (singular taxonomy, multiple terms).

Comment: @ialocin Yes thats what I mean, sorry. Category is the Taxonomy and kitchenware & Painting are terms. So when the user adds terms they will get added to the menu.

I know that there will only be a small number of categories, most likely 4 or 5 max. So this would not be a UI disaster due to the small number of them. I just want an easier quicker, one-click way to view all products from a specific category instead of doing so using a select menu, it would an unnecessarily long way to do something so simple.

I will update the questions to reflect the changes.